# Highchart Y-axis point is not showing

Tags: angular, highcharts

When there's a large difference between Y-axis points, Highcharts is not rendering the smaller point.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnbz3wtx/1/

Code for the chart:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

   /*  plotOptions: {
        series: {
            minPointLength: 2 // I've tried setting minPointLength but it shows even for 0 values
        }
    }, */

    series: [{
        data: [500, 1]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of data value as 0, you can use `null` with `minPointLength`.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories:  ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      minPointLength: 3
    }
  },


  series: [{
    data: [500, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```